# How use pcode to regenerate a file in MatLab?

Tags: matlab

When I run a .m file containing a .p datafile I get the following error message:

> ```
> The P-code file /Users/....
> was generated prior to MATLAB version 7.5 (R2007b) and is no longer supported.  Use pcode
> to regenerate the file using MATLAB R2007b or later.
> ```

How should I use pcode to regenerate the file as suggested by the hint?

I try to type `pcode filename` and `pcode(filename)` but without any success. Any suggestions? Also I should mention that the .m does not work because of this problem so I cannot simply ignore the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Pcode files are byte code translated matlab functions, which are heavily obfuscated during that process.

To solve this problem, you have to get the original m-function which was used to create the pcode file. It typically has the same file name with a different extension. Then you could run `pcode` again, or use the m-code.

Comment: OK so I have to run the og m-function in the newer Matlab version to regenerate the p-code?

Comment: You don't need to run the original m-function, but it must be present on your matlab search path to regenerate the pcode.

Comment: OK. This worked last year but this year there's a problem.

Comment: What problem? Any error message? Maybe you need to delete the old p-code file or the new file was created in the wrong folder. It should replace the old one.

Comment: I mean, it's strange that because of the update to 2015b everything went crazy (the same thing worked last year with the 2014 version) when in the error message is seems to be related to the 2007 update. I don't get it.

Comment: Any matlab version up to Release R2015a had full backwards compatibility to the old formats, since R2015b there is no backwards compatibility and only the new format is supported.

Comment: According to the release notes, this behavior errors starting in R2015b.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#zmw57dd0e349

Comment: What the funk were they thinking designing their new stuff?  Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Matlab 2015b comes with a new execution engine (which runs much faster in many cases). Probably implementing the old pcode format for that new engine was probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Just to be clear, `pcode`d files are not encrypted, they are just obfuscated by being pre-parsed into the format which is directly used by the MATLAB execution engine, which is not human-readable. They are not a secure way of protecting your source code (though it will likely stop most people who aren't very determined). R2015b includes a new execution engine which does not work with the old `pcode` format - this future change was preannounced in the release notes for R2011a, along with advice that you should plan for that change by regenerating any `.p` files you use.

Comment: @SamRoberts: Very interesting, Matlab 2013a documentation says "pcode(fun) encrypts the code in fun.m and produces a file called fun.p," while recent documentation says it does not encrypt. What you say is what's written in the recent documentation.

Comment: @Daniel Yes - they updated the doc in 14a. The old doc was misleading - `pcode` has never actually encrypted files, it just obfuscates them.